# How can I clear a 'textfield'

Tags: tornadofx

I'm trying to write text to a textfield, clear the text and  the write a new text. I can't get rid of the old text. The new is written on the old so I see them both. I'm using choosefile and trying to show the selected file in a textfield so I can confirm the selection.

```
class TestView : View("My View") {
    var tf: TextField by singleAssign()

    override val root = BorderPane()

    init {
        with(root) {
            center = form {
                fieldset("Main") {
                    field("File") {
                        vbox {
                            tf = textfield()
                            tf.text("678")
                            tf.clear()
                            tf.text("999")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to to see '999' in the textfield but I see  both 678 and 999 at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling the `text()` builder on the textfield, so you're basically creating two text elements inside the text field. I think you should take a step back and read the guide before you go further :) Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
class TestView : View("My View") {
    val filename = SimpleStringProperty()

    override val root = borderpane {
        center {
            form {
                fieldset("Main") {
                    field("File") {
                        textfield(filename)
                        button("Browse...").action {
                            val filters = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"))
                            chooseFile("Choose file...", filters).firstOrNull()?.let {
                                filename.value = it.path
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]